# What exactly are expressions that produce *side effects*?

Tags: javascript

I have trouble understanding this paragraph in the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/void:

> This operator allows inserting
>   expressions that produce side effects
>   into places where an expression that
>   evaluates to undefined is desired.

What exactly are expressions that produce *side effects* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function does two things typically: Perform *something* and return a value. Some functions only do one of those things, some do both. For instance the function:

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

Is side-effect free since all it does is return a value and its invocation can always replaced by its return value. On the other hand, something like `alert()` is only called for its side-effects (alerting a user) and never for its return value.

So what `void` operator does is it makes JavaScript ignore the return value and state that all you're interested is the function's side-effects.

Comment: well then why would i need the void at all? i mean i can simply let it return a value but don't use it right..?

Comment: Pretty much everything can be done in multiple ways.  This is just one way of doing it.  It doesn't really get used all that much in reality.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example is a function call.  If you need an "undefined" value, but you also want to call a function that (say) does some DOM manipulation, you can "cast" the result to `void` and have an undefined result.

I definitely don't think that this would be in the "good parts" of the language, though it does get around the bizarre fact that "undefined" is not really a reserved word. The expression `void 0` is definitely going to be **really** undefined.

Comment: so are you saying the only use of `void` is to reliably give us the `undefined` ? (since `undefined` not being a keyword may actually be replaced by another value)

Comment: That's pretty much all it does.  I share any feelings of mystification that the "void" operator may bring you.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(i+=1)` evaluates to `i+1` but has a side effect of incrementing `i` by 1.

The purpose of `void` isn't to mask side effects but specifically for when you *want* side effects, but *don't* want the result of the expression.

Comment: i don't get it. if i don't want the result of the expression, i simply don't use the return result? so why do i need the void for? if i want it to return a undefined, i simply write **return undefined;**

Comment: That works too.  Sometimes you don't want multiple statements though.  You'll likely never use this "void" trick in real life!

Answer (score 1):

'Side Effects' is the result of the function that void takes as an argument.  In this scenario the function F1 returns 'false', but the wrapping it in 'void' essentially 'swallows' that result or 'side effect':

```
var F1 = function() { return false; }
void(F1());
```

Please excuse the gratuitous use of quotes... haha.

Comment: in your example, if you replace your second line with `F1()`, do you agree with me that there is absolutely no difference at all? (i mean if we don't want the return value just don't use it?)

Comment: perhaps. I think the original question was related to the meaning of 'side effects', not whether or not the language feature was particularly valuable.  I personally see no real use for it myself, I was just trying to help you interpret the definition. Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

One example is this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(**do stuff here**)">link</a>
```

The void forces it to return nothing.  Without the void potentially some return value will cause the link to take the user away from the page.

Comment: why do i need the void when i can simply **<a href="do stuff here; return undefined;">link</a>** ?

Comment: Just another way of doing it.